# Class of forcings with an approximation property to subsets of \omega_1

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Is there a class of forcing notions which has the following property?

For every $A \subseteq \omega_1 \cap V[G]$, there exists $A' \subseteq \omega_1 \cap V$ with $|A \triangle A'| \leq \omega$? That is, new subsets of $\omega_1$ are "approximated" by ground model sets, modulo some countable set.

I'm not looking for something like $\omega_1$-closed forcings (that is any descending chain of $\omega_1$-many elements has a lower bound), as these would guarantee that new subsets of $\omega_1$ aren't added at all, etc.

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: Would please add more explanations on origin and background of your question? Providing some references to the context which your question is based on, can help people to provide more accurate and useful answers.

Comment: It's just that there are other sorts of countable approximations that one runs into. For example, if $\mathbb{P}$ is a c.c.c. forcing and $g$ is a function from, say, $A$ to $B$ where $B$ is uncountable, then by noting that for every $a \in A$, $\{b \in B : \exists p \in \mathbb{P} \textrm{ such that p forces that } g(a)=b\}$ countable because for distinct $b, b'$ conditions forcing $g(a)=b$ and $g(a)=b'$ are incompatible, there exists some $g' \in V$ from $A$ to the power set of $B$ which gives a sort of "countable approximation" to $g$.

Comment: Of course that line of reasoning will not work directly here because the antichains associated to a characteristic function are of size two at most.